# plug logistic regression equation into Raster Calculator when one predictor is nominal

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator, regression

I am conducting a study that aims at building a Logistic Regression model for land productivity quality (binary dependent variable: good, no good) using different predictors such as slope, elevation, aspect, distance from coast-line, soil types, etc.

Once I have got my Logistic Regression equation, to get a raster depicting the land productivity quality probability, I have plug into ArcGIS's (10.1)'s Raster Calculator the logistic regression equation. So far so good.

On that respect, I have found a discussion (http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=270065) in which an example has been provided of the formula to put into the Raster Calculator. For example,
`1.0 / (1.0 + Exp( 1.0 - 2.5 * [slope] ))` 
where the third 1.0 is the constant, and -2.5 is the coefficient for the slope, and the [slope] is the slope raster.

Now, one of my predictors is nominal, i.e. soil types.  It has been derived from a feature class where polygons where used to chart the different soil types. 
So, my logistic regression equation would run as follows:
`1.0 / (1.0 + Exp( 1.0 - 2.5 * [slope] + 1.4 * [sandy] ))` 
where 'sandy' is one of the categories making up the 'soil types' raster.

The problem for me is: how can I plug the 'soil types' raster into the logistic regression formula to be used in the Raster Calculator? I mean, how can ArcGIS multiply a nominal value (i.e., sandy) by 1.4.

Comment: You will need to come up with a numeric representation of the nominal values, presumably related to their relative productivity independent of other variables.

Comment: @Erica: thank you for your reply. But I do not quite follow you. My bad. Wahat I have done so far is to convert the polygons representing the soil types into to Raster format, in order to being able to plug the 'soil types' raster into the Raster Calculator. But the issue I have described upon opening this thread still remains. While I have no problem in plugging LR formula into Raster Calculator and get a Raster of LR results (i.e., map of probability of land productivity quality) when all the variables are continuous, I do not  grasp how a (raster) layer with nominal values can be used.

Comment: @Erica: were you meaning that the nominal values of the 'soil types' raster should be converted into class codes (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, etc)?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was not clear. The raster calculator cannot do math without a numeric input, and so a nominal raster has to be somehow turned into a numeric raster. I think (trying to recall my stats classes) that would be like dummy variables in logistic regression, although I also seem to recall that those are typically binary (e.g. 0 for sandy soil, 1 for not-sandy soil). Since you've got multiple soil types, it may be trickier and is perhaps a question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Erica:thank you. Now it is quite more clear. I have made a search, and I found this article (Landslide susceptibility mapping: A comparison of logistic regression and neural networks methods in a medium scale study, Hendek region (Turkey); http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0013795205000384) in which the Authors make reference to the issue I have raised, and propose a 'solution'.

Comment: @Erica: as for their strategy, quotation "These data sets (i.e., geology), in vector format,
were converted into raster format. The conversion of
parameters from nominal to numeric can be done through the creation of dummy variables or by coding and ranking the classes based on the relative percentage of the area affected by landsliding. The two methods are similar but the latter is to be preferred for two reasons. It avoids the creation of an excessively high number of dummy variables...". Now, I was wondering if anyone here has an idea on how to practically make the coding and ranking...

Comment: In my case, I got a number of sampling points for which I know if land productivity is optimal or non-optimal. On the other hand, I got a vector layers with polygons being areas with different soil types. Now, with reference to the quoted approach, I guess I could calculate the proportion of optima/non-optimal occurrences in each 'soil type' polygon. Then, create a ranking, whose values should be 'transferred' to an exported vector-to-raster raster. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense to me. I did a similar "translation" for a suitability/cost surface before. The primary goal is to have a reasonable justification for your numeric ranking/coding, and calculating it from sampling points is certainly reasonable.